# onblur event and Gecko browsers - MDN clarification

Tags: javascript, gecko, onblur

I read on Mozilla Developer Network the following note:

> In contrast to MSIE--in which almost all kinds of elements receive the
> blur event--almost all kinds of elements on Gecko browsers do NOT work
> with this event.<sup>1</sup>

However, I do not observe this behavior in Firefox 25.0.1, which I understand to be Gecko based.

As can be observed in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4knrk/), `onblur` event is being fired. This seems to contradict the above statement?

Is the case in this fiddle one of the ambiguous exceptions to the note?

Am I misunderstanding what this statement is suggesting? If so, what is meant by it?

---

#### References

1. [GlobalEventHandlers.onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onblur?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FElement.onblur#Notes) - MDN Reference

Comment: Dunno what they mean. It works even on SPANs http://jsfiddle.net/4knrk/1

Comment: I tested IE11, firefox 26 and chrome 32 on windows 7. As long as the element has a tabindex the three browser behave the same. http://jsfiddle.net/uScaY/1/

Comment: Is there a way we can ask Mozilla specifically what they meant?

Answer (score 0):

What they mean is that the majority of elements do not fire onblur events (e.g. a div tag that has an input as a child). IE seems to behave differently.